# How to mirror iPod Touch 4th-gen to TV?

Tags: ipod-touch, jailbreak, ios, tweaks, mirroring

I have an iPod Touch 4th-generation currently running the latest iOS software supported by it (iOS 6.1.6), and it is jailbroken.  I am trying to find a solution to mirror its screen to a TV.

As this is not an iPod Touch 5th-generation model, I cannot use AirPlay Mirroring to mirror it.  So I bought an official [Apple 30-pin to Analog AV Adapter](http://store.storeimages.cdn-apple.com/4491/as-images.apple.com/is/image/AppleInc/aos/published/images/M/C7/MC748/MC748?wid=1200&hei=630&fmt=jpeg&qlt=95&op_sharpen=0&resMode=bicub&op_usm=0.5,0.5,0,0&iccEmbed=0&layer=comp&.v=1400778687374).  This cable works with the iOS internal video player and a few of other apps (such as Keynote), but I would like to mirror the entire iPod Touch screen to my TV through this cable, so allow all other apps can be presented on TV.

I used to use [TVOut2 Mirror TVOut](http://apt.thebigboss.org/onepackage.php?bundleid=com.tvout2.tvout2tuner) tweak when I had iOS 5, but this tweak no longer works with iOS 6, and so far I have not any other working method to mirror the screen. Has anyone else found a solution to mirror the screen with the cable (without wireless mirroring)

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

### Mirroring iPod Touch 4th Gen Completely (homescreen and games) !!

If you are jailbroken, then you can go into iFile and go to the directory:
(/var/mobile/Library/Preferences)
Then go to the plist named: (com.apple.springboard.plist) Open the plist up with the Property List Viewer and scroll down until you find the line labelled TVOutDiabled and turn that switch to "off". The Line underneath that will have "TVOutOrientation", tap on this line and change it's value to "1" instead of "0" Now quit out of iFile on your iOS device and you should be good to go.

---

This tutorial is only for mirroring your device with a cable (such as 30Pin to VGA, or other cables like 30Pin to HDMI)

---

You can also try editing the .plist file with a program such as iFunbox or Anytrans but I can't garantee that it would work.